# "Client not ready yet.. "occured when I installed and opened the sample app on Samsung Knox "hardware-access"

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-knox

lately, I am learning developing on Samsung Knox based on its SDK on Android Studio. "hardware-access" is the sample app I downloaded on its official website.But when I trying to install on my Samsung Phone Galaxy S5, the phone cannot open the app and alerts "Sample2 has stopped"; Android Studio prints these:

```
06/22 08:37:10: Launching app
    No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\workspace\aisino\download-codes\Samsung\Sample2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    $adb shell am force-stop           com.samsung.android.sdk.b2b.samples.cSDKsample2
    $adb shell am start -n "com.samsung.android.sdk.b2b.samples.cSDKsample2/com.samsung.android.sdk.b2b.samples.cSDKsample2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Client not ready yet..
```